# SSRS Visual Studio 2013 - turn number into percentage

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I have a very simple question about how to turn a number into a percentage, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

So here is an example of what I have

```
gender  COHORT  COHORT % 
M        150      50% 
F        150      50%
```

I have the first two columns, but need to calculate the third.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The third column will be the percentage of what?

Comment: It is the cohort percentage, so the percentage of the total of the cohort column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the third column:

```
=FORMAT(Fields!COHORT.Value / SUM(Fields!COHORT.Value,"DateSetName"),"P2")
```

Note `P2` stands for Percentage with two decimals. Also replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

**UPDATE:** If you are grouping your tablix by gender field.

Try this:

```
=FORMAT(SUM(Fields!COHORT.Value,"gender") / SUM(Fields!COHORT.Value,"DateSetName"),"P2")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. I had already tried =Fields!COHORT.Value / SUM(Fields!COHORT.Value) but this just gives me 1 in both columns.

Comment: @BeckyLouisePurland, Do you have groups in your tablix? Also exactly what do you mean by this did not work, shows an error or a wrong value?

Comment: Hi, the first one gave an error but the second one calculates, but I get 100% on both.